# Отправка данных Vue в mySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных, vue.js, форма

Возник вопрос: как отправлять данные, которые хранятся в Vue?

Я знаю, что:

- можно через `AJAX`
- можно через метод `fetch`
- `axios` (только получение данных)

Как связать эти способы с Vue?

---

Данные, которые хранит Vue - это массив, который хранит массив, который хранит еще один массив.

То есть массив таблиц, и каждая такая таблица содержит массив имен пользователей с персональными данными.

Как реализовать отправку таких данных?

Comment: данные из и в бд отправляются/получаются через сервер, если хотите с фронта использовать БД, то лучший вариант и единственный(могу ошибаться) это Firebase с его Firestore (Vuefire для Vue)

Comment: Могу я у вас узнать, можно ли через AJAX отправлять данные vue.js ?

Comment: покажите пример массива,, отправленные данные на бэк можно обработать непосредственно там и передать уже в таблицу

Comment: https://github.com/AmanKKK/ListEditor.git
тут находятся весь проект

Comment: Если быть точнее касательного моего вопроса , то как отправить на сервер массив, каждый элемент которого также является массивом, в котором есть еще один массив ?